# jquery complex selector by element and class starting with

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using **jQuery** in my website.
I want to select all the `<hr>` elements through jQuery when class starts with **line-rooms-sphere**. `<hr>` elements have more than one class.

This is my html:

```
<hr class="line-rooms-sphere-4 rooms-hidden"/>
// There are 5 hr like this one
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$('hr [class^="line-rooms-sphere"]') // => Not working, Why?
$('[class^="line-rooms-sphere"]')    // => This Works well
```

I want to get all the `<hr>` elements when they have the wanted class (in this case, starting with `line-rooms-sphere`).

Any help? Thanks

Comment: can you include html?

Comment: It's already there, is the `hr` code. Or what you asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example:

```
$('hr [class^="line-rooms-sphere"]') // => Not working, Why?
```

Does not work as you have a space between the `hr` and the attribute selector. The jQuery selector engine follows CSS rules, so a space means that the second rule should be looked for *within* the first selected element.

Instead the attribute you want is on the `hr` itself, so no space is required:

```
$('hr[class^="line-rooms-sphere"]');
```

Comment: Well, that's all? So easy, but I didn't get it. Was trying a lot of ways, but not this one. Thanks, it works great.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

There should be no space between "hr" and "[class... ]" in the selector "$('hr [class^="line-rooms-sphere"]'". Check this snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <hr class="line-rooms-sphere-4 rooms-hidden"/>

    <hr class="line-rooms-sphere-4 rooms-hidden"/>

    <hr class="line-rooms-sphere-4 rooms-hidden"/>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
      $('hr[class^="line-rooms-sphere"]').css("border-width","8px");
      
     });

    </script>
```